# TypeError: _firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.db.collection is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, npm, google-cloud-firestore

```
// src/services/firebase.js
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
 //Assume all congif details are present
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = getFirestore(app);

export { db };
```

```
// src/services/firestoreService.js
import { db } from './firebase';

export const addUrlToFirestore = async (longUrl, shortCode, timestamp) => {
  try {
    await db.collection('urls').doc(shortCode).set({
      longurl: longUrl,
      timestamp: timestamp
    });
    console.log('URL added to Firestore:', { longUrl, shortCode, timestamp });
    return true; // Return true if successful
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error adding URL to Firestore:', error);
    return false; // Return false if an error occurs
  }
};
```

NODE JS VERSION : 21.6.2 (latest)
FIREBASE VERSION : 10.8.0 (latest)
FIRESTORE VERSION : 4.4.2 (latest)

I tried to restart it, clear cache etc

Comment: The `db.collection` call only exists in the namespaced API of Firebase, but your code uses the modular API. There the equivalent is a top-level `collection` function. So you'll need to import that separately and then call is as `collection(db)` or the whole chain as `document(db, 'urls', shortCode)`. I recommend reading this [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade) and keeping it handy.